# Facing API Validation failed error while creating new User in Okta

Tags: java, okta, okta-api

I'm using `okta-sdk-java` in my application to implement `okta` based login authentication. I'm able to successfully login the app with the user created in `Okta developer console`. but while trying to create a new user to my okta application-group through code, I'm getting the **API Validation failed error**

**I've tried** as mentioned in the Git hub article, I've created a new Token in `Okta developer console`. I have copied the created super api token and used it in the application like below

```java
private String oktaBaseUri;
private String oktaDomain;
private AuthenticationClient oktaAuthClient;
private String relayState;
private Client oktaClient;
private String apiToken;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
        oktaBaseUri = System.getProperty("okta.base.uri", "http://localhost:8080");
        oktaDomain = System.getProperty("okta.domain", "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com");
        relayState = System.getProperty("relay.state", "/app.menu/");
        apiToken = System.getProperty("okta.api.token", "00XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXeg");
        buildOktaClient();
}

private void buildOktaClient() {
        oktaAuthClient = AuthenticationClients.builder().setOrgUrl(oktaDomain).build();
        oktaClient = Clients.builder().setClientCredentials(new TokenClientCredentials(apiToken)).setOrgUrl(oktaDomain).build();
}

public User createOktaUser(ObjectVO objectVO) {
        User user = null;
        UserBuilder userBuilder = UserBuilder.instance().setEmail(objectVO.getUpn()).setFirstName(objectVO.getFirstNm()).setLastName(objectVO.getLastNm()).setPassword(objectVO.getPassword().toCharArray());
        userBuilder.setActive(true);
        user = userBuilder.buildAndCreate(oktaClient);
        user.addToGroup("my-group");
        return user;
}
```

**The expected result** is that the new user should be created under "my-group" group but getting the below error

```
Caused by: com.okta.sdk.resource.ResourceException: HTTP 400, Okta E0000001 (Api validation failed: login - '3 causes'), ErrorId oaevTzn-FnlTVGpgmb32W9K4A
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.execute(DefaultDataStore.java:453)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.lambda$save$1(DefaultDataStore.java:314)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:47)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.cache.WriteCacheFilter.filter(WriteCacheFilter.java:34)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52)
```

Comment: The error message mentions `3 causes`. Okta documentation (on https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#get-user) makes me believe that somewhere in the HTTP response there should be a JSON array with three _causes_ in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons to get this error with Error code `E0000001  API validation failed`.

One of the prominent reason would be password pattern or sequence. There are password rules defined for Okta integration.

**Basic rule: Password 'Does not contain any part of username/email' logically**

Examples:

Username *`mike.ross@business.com`* contains the following parts: mike, ross and business. *If User attempts to set password to **mike123456**.  Password is not accepted, because mike is considered as a username/email "part".*

May this helps.